# Turtle in python- Trying to get the turtle to move to the mouse click position and print its coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get the mouse position through Python turtle. Everything works except that I cannot get the turtle to jump to the position of the mouse click.

```
import turtle

def startmap(): #the next methods pertain to drawing the map
   screen.bgcolor("#101010")
   screen.title("Welcome, Commadore.")
   screen.setup(1000,600,1,-1)
   screen.setworldcoordinates(0,600,1000,0)
   drawcontinents()    #draws a bunch of stuff, works as it should but not really important to the question
   turtle.pu()
   turtle.onclick(turtle.goto)
   print(turtle.xcor(),turtle.ycor())
   screen.listen()
```

As I understand, the line that says 'turtle.onclick(turtle.goto)' should send the turtle to wherever I click the mouse, but it does not. The print line is a test, but it only ever returns the position that I sent the turtle last, nominally (0, 650) although this does not have major significance.

I tried looking up tutorials and in the pydoc, but so far I have not been able to write this successfully.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Edit: I need the turtle to go to the click position(done) but I also need it to print the coordinates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`onscreenclick()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick). It is a method of `TurtleScreen`. The [`onclick()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) method of a `Turtle` refers to mouse clicks on the turtle itself. Confusingly, the `onclick()` method of `TurtleScreen` is the same thing as its `onscreenclick()` method.

> #### 24.5.4.3. Using screen events[¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#using-screen-events)
>
> `turtle.onclick`(*fun*, *btn=1*, *add=None*)
>   `turtle.onscreenclick`(*fun*, *btn=1*, *add=None*)[¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **fun** – a function with two arguments which will be called with the coordinates of the clicked point on the canvas
> - **num** – number of the mouse-button, defaults to 1 (left mouse button)
> - **add** – **`True`** or **`False`** – if **`True`**, a new binding will be added, otherwise it will replace a former binding
>
> Bind *fun* to mouse-click events on this screen. If *fun* is **`None`**, existing bindings are removed.
>
> Example for a TurtleScreen instance named `screen` and a Turtle instance named turtle:

```
>>> screen.onclick(turtle.goto) # Subsequently clicking into the TurtleScreen will
>>>                             # make the turtle move to the clicked point.
>>> screen.onclick(None)        # remove event binding again
```

> **Note**: This TurtleScreen method is available as a global function only under the name `onscreenclick`. The global function `onclick` is another one derived from the Turtle method `onclick`.

### Cutting to the quick...

So, just invoke the method of `screen` and not `turtle`. It is as simple as changing it to:

```
screen.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)
```

If you had typed `turtle.onclick(lambda x, y: fd(100))` (or something like that) you would probably have seen the turtle move forward when you clicked on it. With `goto` as the `fun` argument, you would see the turtle go to... its own location.

#### Printing every time you move

If you want to print every time you move, you should define your own function which will do that as well as tell the turtle to go somewhere. I think this will work because `turtle` is a singleton.

```
def gotoandprint(x, y):
    gotoresult = turtle.goto(x, y)
    print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
    return gotoresult

screen.onscreenclick(gotoandprint)
```

If `turtle.goto()` returns `None` (I wouldn't know), then you can actually do this:

```
screen.onscreenclick(lambda x, y: turtle.goto(x, y) or print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
```

Let me know if this works. I don't have tk on my computer so I can't test this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up for me. I'm confused as to why the print statement is still not giving me the location of the turtle. I tried putting it in several places. How do I get the location of the turtle that it just moved to?

Comment: @Jack You need to print every time you have moved.

Comment: Ah thank you, I could not get a separate function working. This does accomplish what I needed for my program.

Comment: What happens when you make the function call with no arguments, even though the definition calls for arguments in the function?

Comment: @Jack I don't know what you mean. The `fun` in `onscreenclick()` must be a function which takes two arguments. Both `gotoandprint()` and that lambda take two arguments. Are you referring to the fact that there are no parentheses after `gotoandprint`? That's because it refers to the function *object*. Parentheses are the syntax for invoking the `__call__` method of objects. Try writing a function in the interactive shell and then typing *just* the function name, without parentheses, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I learned later that what I was asking about callback functions. I think I need to learn a bit more about OOP.

Comment: why is it useful to know the (x, y) coordinates when you click the turtle? isn't that, in effect if not reality, just `turtle.pos()`?