# Trigger event when text is clicked in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm currently making a program in python's Turtle Graphics. Here is my code in case you need it

```
import turtle
turtle.ht()

width = 800
height = 800
turtle.screensize(width, height)

##Definitions
def text(text, size, color, pos1, pos2):
     turtle.penup()
     turtle.goto(pos1, pos2)
     turtle.color(color)
     turtle.begin_fill()
     turtle.write(text, font=('Arial', size, 'normal'))
     turtle.end_fill()

##Screen
turtle.bgcolor('purple')
text('This is an example', 20, 'orange', 100, 100)


turtle.done()
```

I want to have click events. So, where the text `'This is an example'` is wrote, I want to be able to click that and it prints something to the console or changes the background. How do I do this?

I don't want to install anything like pygame, it has to be made in Turtle

Comment: Updated my old post that would change screen color when clicked anywhere to change screen color only specific to text area position as per requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requirement is to have `onscreenclick` around text area, we need 
to track mouse position. For that we are binding function `onTextClick` to the screenevent.
Within function, if we are anywere around text `This is an example` , a call is made to `turtle.onscreenclick` to change color of the background to `red`.
You can change lambda function and insert your own, or just create external function and call within `turtle.onscreenclick` as per [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick)

I tried to change your code as little as possible.

**Here is a working Code:**

```
import turtle

turtle.ht()

width = 800
height = 800
turtle.screensize(width, height)

##Definitions
def text(text, size, color, pos1, pos2):
     turtle.penup()
     turtle.goto(pos1, pos2)
     turtle.color(color)
     turtle.begin_fill()
     turtle.write(text, font=('Arial', size, 'normal'))
     turtle.end_fill()


def onTextClick(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('x={}, y={}'.format(x, y))    
    if (x >= 600 and x <= 800) and (  y >= 280 and y <= 300):
        turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x, y: turtle.bgcolor('red'))

##Screen
turtle.bgcolor('purple')
text('This is an example', 20, 'orange', 100, 100)

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
canvas.bind('<Motion>', onTextClick)    

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the onscreenclick method to get the position then act on it in your mainloop (to print or whatever).

```
import turtle as t

def main():
    t.onscreenclick(getPos)
    t.mainloop()
main()
```

Also see : [Python 3.0 using turtle.onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893236/python-3-0-using-turtle-onclick)
Also see : [Turtle in python- Trying to get the turtle to move to the mouse click position and print its coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864085/turtle-in-python-trying-to-get-the-turtle-to-move-to-the-mouse-click-position-a)